# Tabgroup iOS tab won't open new view, gives Obj-C error

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, appcelerator, nscfstring

Currently working on getting the code for my app to run on the iOS side after hitting a milestone on Android. I have a tabgroup in my `index.xml`:

```
<Alloy>
  <TabGroup id="tabMenu" title="USHUD | Home" tabsBackgroundColor="Alloy.CFG.design.colors.hudGrey" tabsBackgroundSelectedColor="Alloy.CFG.design.colors.hudBlue">
    // ------------------------------------   SEARCH TAB  --------------------------------------------------
    <Require src="search_tab/search"/>
    // ------------------------------------ FAVORITES TAB --------------------------------------------------
    <Require src="favorites"/>
    // ------------------------------------   ABOUT TAB  ---------------------------------------------------
    <Require src="about"/>
  </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

and it's controller `index.js`:

```
/**
 * The scoped constructor of the controller.
 **/
(function constructor() {
  //Alloy.CFG.tabGroup = index.getView('tabMenu');
  globalTabGroup = $.tabMenu;
  $.tabMenu.open();
})();
```

I'm trying to add a view to the search tab's navigation stack when the button gets clicked in `search_tab/search.xml`:

```
<Alloy>
<Tab id='searchTab' class="homeTab" title="Search" icon='/images/search-1.png'>
    <Window id="searchWin" title="Property Search">
        <View class="vgroup" id="wrapper">
            <ImageView height="Titanium.UI.SIZE" left="20" id="hud_logo" image="/images/US.png"/>
            <Button class="button-default bottom" id="buttonSearch" onClick="startSearch" title="Begin Search" zIndex="1"/>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Tab>
```

`search_tab/search.js`:

```
// Arguments passed into this controller can be accessed via the $.args object directly or:
var args = $.args;

function startSearch(e){
  if(OS_ANDROID){
      Alloy.createController("search_tab/states").getView().open();
  }else if(OS_IOS){
      //Ti.API.debug('Current Window: '+Ti.UI.currentWindow);
      //Ti.API.debug('Current Tab: '+Ti.UI.currentTab);
      //Ti.UI.currentTab.open('search_tab/states');

    globalTabGroup.activeTab.open('search_tab/states');
    //$.searchTab.open('search_tab/states');

    //Alloy.Globals.tabGroup.activeTab.open('search_tab/states');
    //Alloy.createController("search_tab/states").getView().open();
  }
}
```

I have tried a few different approaches trying to get a reference to the active tab so that I can call that tab's `open()` function and add the next view in the search tab navigation stack. However, no matter how I try it I get this cryptic, vague error.

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error {
[ERROR] :      column = 332;
[ERROR] :      line = 1;
[ERROR] :      message = "-[__NSCFString setIsManaged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e61000";
[ERROR] :      sourceURL = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7D2E0E41-E28B-40F8-90D1-485279A0B8F6/USHUD.app/alloy/controllers/search_tab/search.js";
[ERROR] :      stack = "[native code]\ne@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7D2E0E41-E28B-40F8-90D1-485279A0B8F6/USHUD.app/alloy/controllers/search_tab/search.js:1:332";
[ERROR] :  }
```

Through research I found that the NSCFString is a wrapper for NSString and that isSetManaged is a variable of boolean type(?) that is getting a string somewhere(?). I don't know a lick of Obj-C so this is all inference on my end as to what the error actually means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, you are passing a string to **activeTab.open() method**, not a window controller. But in android you are creating a controller and then you are calling open method of controller which works correctly.

So this code will definitely work for you:

**index.js**

```
/**
 * The scoped constructor of the controller.
 **/
(function constructor() {
  Alloy.Globals.globalTabGroup = $.tabMenu;
  $.tabMenu.open();
})();
```

**search_tab/search.js:**

```
// Arguments passed into this controller can be accessed via the $.args object directly or:
var args = $.args;

function startSearch(e){
  var statesWin = Alloy.createController("search_tab/states").getView();

  OS_IOS ? Alloy.Globals.globalTabGroup.activeTab.open(statesWin) : statesWin.open();
}
```

Comment: Since switching to this method every window on the Android side closes on exit. I have `exitOnClose` set to false for every Android Window. Any thoughts on this behavior?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that adding exitOnClose to my root windows in my tabgroups removed the behavior on the rest of the windows deeper in the app.